# Pybossa : How are answers stored and evaluated

Tags: pybossa

I am working on a Pybossa based crowdsourcing platform. In the task presented I am stuck on the following code -

```
$(".btn-submit").off('click').on('click', function(){
        var answer = $("textarea#text").val();
        $("#viewport_" + task.id).hide();
        pybossa.saveTask(task.id, answer).done(function(data){
            deferred.resolve();
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#success").fadeOut() }, 2000);
        })
    });
```

This code is for fetching the reply and storing it as `answer`

What if I have many questions in a task to which user replies, structured as follows -

```
Q.1 This is question 1?
Q.2 This is question 2?
Q.3 This is question 3?
```

And the user replies to these in separate text forms -

```
answer1

answer2

answer3
```

How do I store multiple answers, in a way that Pybossa can also take weighted average of each while calculating results (For example via **Golden Tasks**.) I would also like to know how Pybossa evaluates answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to do a similar thing. The solution I have so far is to construct a Javascript object and save it into the taskrun results. Later I will parse this and extract the fields I want.

I create an HTML form:

```
<form action = "">
<input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname">
<input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname">
<select class="span2" name="gender">
   <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Then in the pybossa.saveTask method construct an answer object:

```
var firstname = $("input[name='firstname']").val();
var lastname = $("input[name='lastname']").val();
var gender = $("select[name='gender']").val();

var answer = {
  firstname: firstname,
  lastname: lastname,
  gender: gender   
 };
```

But this doesn't answer the second part of your question, ie how to enable PyBossa to take a weighted average of results.

Comment: Yes exactly. What I want to k ownis how pyBossa evaluates answers in the results.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that helped a lot! If possible, could you please consider upvoting this question if you felt that this question is helpful for the PyBossa community?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by ch4s is correct. For the second part you will need to use the [webhooks solution of PYBOSSA](https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks).

You will need to use the webhooks, to notify that microservice when all the task_runs have been achieved. Then, the system will download it, process it, and generate a result. As it uses Enki and the API of PYBOSSA you can do anything that you want:

- Requesting more task_runs for the same task (in other words, increasing the task redundancy via n_answers field).
- Send an email with the results to anyone that you want.
- Update the social networks of your choice with the information about the results.
- Use the new web push notifications of PYBOSSA to notify your users about a new result (we do this in [Sr. Alergeno](https://sralergeno.pybossa.com)

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that helped a lot! If possible, could you please consider upvoting this question if you felt that this question is helpful for the PyBossa community?